# Math.pow(0.0, 0.0) returns 1; should be undefined or error ?

Tags: java, math, pow

`Math.pow(0.0, 0.0)` in Java returns 1 which is wrong. 0^0 is undefined. The same problem exists also in the windows calculator (I am using Win7). Why is that?

Mathematica declares it as an error as well as my Casio scientific calculator, why not java or the Win calculator... Is it a bug?

Answer (score 8):

0^0 = 1 is considered a reasonable definition in many contexts. For a list of arguments for and against it, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero

Answer (score 5):

Because that's exactly what the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) say it will do:

> public static double pow(double a, double b)
> Returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument. Special cases:
>   * If the second argument is positive or negative zero, then the result is 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a bug?

No, a bug is something that violates the specification. The [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) states:

> Returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument. Special cases:
>
> - If the second argument is positive or negative zero, then the result is 1.0.

Finally, mathematically, [some do define](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) `0^0` as `1`. In fact, Knuth [says](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9205211) that it *has* to be `1`.

> The number of mappings from the empty set to the empty set is `0^0`. It *has* to be `1`.

His reasoning is as follows. If you have two sets, `A` and `B`, the number of functions from `A` to `B` is `|B|^|A|`. How many functions are there from the empty set to the empty set? Well, there is exactly one. By this logic, `0^0` *should* be `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Java defines it that way. That's all you can really say.

However, mathematically it *is* an undefined quantity. One way to see why is to write

x = 0 ^ 0

where I've used ^ to represent exponentiation. Taking logarithms,

log x = 0 log 0

I've done this since every mathematician accepts that log 0 is undefined and so it follows that log x and therefore x are undefined too. (Mathematically it's called a singularity and a mathematician will tell you that it's one of the worst singularities you can encounter).

Comment: I'm a mathematician and it's not one of the worst singularities that you can encounter, just a limit :)

Comment: Whether `log 0` is undefined depends on the context. If it's about logarithms of non-negative real numbers, `log 0 = -infinity` is the commonly accepted value.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, but what type of infinity? That's when things get really interesting.

Comment: The type you get from the two-point compactification of the real line.

Comment: The worst singularity that you can encounter is a black hole.

Comment: @Jason I thought you couldn't encounter that, you'd be history before.

Comment: @Jason, I'm not sure about that; I'd like to witness the end of the universe. Bring on that black hole...

Comment: Yes, I know I am a mathematician myself. But why not returning lets say NaN such as when divide zero with 0 (0.0/0.0). It would be better and would not lead to false calculation when it is used

Comment: @user2512326: The documentation is unambiguous. It says exactly what will happen if you invoke `Math.pow(0.0, 0.0)`. You say that you don't like that. If it hurts when you do that then do not do that! If you need the result of `Math.pow(0.0, 0.0)` to be `Double.NaN`, then you need to test for these inputs before invoking `Math.pow` and use `Double.NaN` instead of blindly passing those parameters along to `Math.pow` and not getting the result that you want. Mathematicians do not universally agree on `0^0`, saying it's `1` is acceptable, so Java's choice is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The exact definition of the function's behavior is given at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)

You will see here that

```
public static double pow(double a,
         double b)
Returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument. Special cases:
If the second argument is positive or negative zero, then the result is 1.0.
```

Not a bug - it's by design.

Comment: But why not returning lets say NaN such as when divide zero with 0 (0.0/0.0). It would be better and would not lead to false calculation when it is used. Mathematica returns Indeterminate which is also true...

Comment: Ask the people who made this design decision. If you say "anything to the power zero is one" there is no problem...

Comment: Thanks a lot I've got your point. That's why I am asking this question, it's about this incompatible design decision. It would be also strange and incompatible if 0.0/0.0 returns 1. Thanks anyway, I appreciate your answer and the time you have spent!